# One question about Manetti surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, algebraic-surfaces, k-stability

I am reading Ascher-Devleming-Liu's paper "Wall crossing for K-moduli spaces of plane curves" theorem 5.2 [ADL19](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.04576) and l have some confusions about the proof.

Theorem 5.2 states that fixed a positive rational number $c < \frac{3}{2d}$ (resp. $c < \frac{3}{2d-3}$), a plane curve $C$ of even (resp. odd) degree $d$ is $GIT$ (poly/semi)stable if and only if the log Fano pair ($\mathbb{P^2}$, $c$$C$) is $K$-(poly/semi)stable.

In the proof of theorem 5.2, it initially proves that if pair ($X$, $cD$) is $K$-semistable, then $X$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{P^2}$. By index bounds, we know in this case, $X$ is a Gorenstein Manetti surface (resp. Gorenstein index at most 3).

My first question is how to deduce $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P^2}$ (resp. $\mathbb{P^2}$ or $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$). l only know that for all weighted projective spaces $\mathbb{P}(a^2, b^2, c^2)$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=3abc$, $X$  can only smooth to $\mathbb{P^2}$ (resp. $\mathbb{P^2}$ or $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$).

My second question is whether the Manetti surface with the small $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein index can only become weighted projective space$?$ Any comments are welcome. Thank you very much.